# Need onclick to be button not hotlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, submit

I have the following code that creates a pop-up lightbox. However, it only shows up as a text link. I need there to be a button for people to click. I know virtually nothing about coding but have gotten this far - I'm sooo close. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">var hide_awf_Form = true;</script>

<div class="AW-Form-##########"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//forms.aweber.com/form/39/#########.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-rb4ygt9a4"));
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="awf_Form_.showForm(); return false;"> Grab our Ideas Newsletter here!</a>
```

I need the "Grab our Ideas Newsletter here!" text to be on a button instead of just as text but with the same functionality.

(Note - I inserted the ####### for my Aweber numbers)

Thanks for any help!

~Vicky

Answer (score 1):

Change it from an "a" tag to a "button" tag, like this:

```
<button onclick="awf_Form_.showForm(); return false;"> Grab our Ideas Newsletter here!</button>
```

Comment: That worked - how do I edit the button characteristics - size, color, font, size.

Comment: Look up a tutorial on how to use CSS -- it'll let you customize the appearance of just about anything. edit: [Here's a pretty good one.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the 'anchor' tag, this is a 'hyperlink'. You want to be using a button as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="awf_Form_.showForm(); return false;">Grab our Ideas Newsletter here!<</button>
```

If you still want to link the button to a page/other content, then use the href attribute.

Comment: This worked, but now I need to edit the formatting of the button. Ideas?